# Relative Layout not working inside Material Card View. Can not close Relative Layout Tag

Tags: android, xml

Hi im new to Android/XML  I'm trying  to create Relative layout inside material card view but the relative layout  closing tag giving me error "Wrong way to Close this Tag" and says replace Material Card View with Relative Layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/bookimg"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/booktitle"
            android:text="Book Title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        </RelativeLayout>


</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Kindly try LinearLayout.

Comment: you can use LinearLayout for this, but in your code, you miss  > on relative layout. <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

Comment: <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> Here you missed >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be like this

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/bookimg"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/booktitle"
            android:text="Book Title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        </RelativeLayout>


</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```